# rake on windows: bad interpreter: permission denied

Tags: ruby, rake

I have JRuby and Git for windows installed. I then installed Ruby 2.3 x64 using RubyInstaller. I then installed the x64 devkit. I installed the json gem and it ran correctly. Running `rake --version` gives me the error:

bash: /c/Ruby23-x64/bin/rake: C:/Users/Justin/Projects/rubyinstaller/sandbox/ruby23_mingw/bin/ruby.exe: bad interpreter: Permission denied

My name is not Justin, there are no users on my computer or network named Justin, and I don't even have any friends named Justin. What is causing this issue?

Comment: try opening cmd as administrator: right click cmd and run as administrator

Comment: it works in cmd. Why won't it work in mingw64?

Comment: @nirupa I figured it out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go into the bin folder of your ruby installation and edit the rake file. Change the first line from `#!C:/Users/Justin/Projects/rubyinstaller/sandbox/ruby23_mingw/bin/ruby.exe` to `#!ruby.exe` or the absolute path your ruby executable if its not in your PATH.

Comment: so you had to set the path

Comment: No my path was already set. The rake command was referencing a ruby exe on the dev's machine